# How to set a four parallel DIV with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I searched for tutorials, but they only show how to set three parallel divs.

Is it possible to change this code, and put 4 parallel divs?

```
<div style="width:90%;border:1px solid #000;">
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%; background:#aaa;">one</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.3%; background:#bbb;">two</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:33.4%; background:#ccc;">three</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div style="width:90%;border:1px solid #000;">
    <div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#aaa;">one</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#bbb;">two</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#ccc;">three</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#ddd;">four</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, I thought I was fast with the answer.. ;)

Comment: Where does the first `div` end ?

Comment: It's obvious to someone experienced, but you may want to add a small note on how/what you changed.

Comment: @abhitalks, you're right, it's a syntax error from origin (just added the fourt div to the code), seems as if it wasn't postet complete. So, each opening div has to have a closing div...

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#aaa;">one</div>
<div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#bbb;">two</div>
<div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#ccc;">three</div>
<div style="float:left; width:25%; background:#ddd;">four</div>
```

Just adding one more div tag and dividing them equally will get u four divs!